# Mapfish printing application from Openlayers : disableScaleLocking

Tags: openlayers-2, printing, scale, mapfish

Mapfish printing application from Openlayers: I get the following error when I use a different scale than the scales defined in the config.yaml even though I am using  `disableScaleLocking: true`

> Error while generating PDF:
>   org.mapfish.print.InvalidJsonValueException: spec.pages[0].scale has an invalid value: 65000

I thought that `disableScaleLocking: true` would enable me to print a map at any scale and not only the ones defined in config.yaml . Did I get it wrong?

Here are the first lines of my config.yaml :

```
dpis: [75, 150, 300]

scales:
   ... (list of predefined scales)

hosts:
    - !localMatch
        dummy: true
    - !ipMatch
        ip: 0.0.0.0
        mask: 0.0.0.0

disableScaleLocking: true

layouts:
      ...
```

Comment: Seems like this should work. Be sure to reload your app/web server after making changes to config.yaml.